# jQuery: отправка формы не переходя по ссылке

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

На странице есть множество ссылок, нажав можно перейти на форму, можно ли сделать так, чтобы не переходя по ссылке а с помощью `Ajax` отправлять формы по нажатию на кнопку. Кнопок будет тоже очень много на форме, поэтому нужно будет сделать одну глобальную кнопку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть, чтобы такое реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите на уроки обработки ajax-форм. Например: [раз](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/) и [два](http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/). Они достаточно подробные, после них количество вопросов значительно поубавится.

Comment: А если форму заполнять не нужно, форма генерируется автоматически, но она на другой странице и нужно нажимать на этой форме submit не заходя на эту страницу?